# How connect a UIButton to the UIViewController Exit with code Swift

Tags: uibutton, swift4, uistoryboardsegue, xcode9, unwind-segue

Lets say I have two `UIViewController`s, we'll call them `VC1` and `VC2`. `VC1` performs a segue that then goes to `VC2`, and `VC2` has a close button that will unwind that segue back to `VC1`.

So normally, if I'm wanting to make a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` I would make a segue from `VC1` to `VC2` and then select custom and use my custom `UIStoryboardSegue` I made that and I have it working just fine.

And for the close button I would put in code in the destination `UIViewController` (`VC1`) like this:

```
@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    //some code
}
```

Then on the `UIViewController` with the close button, I would ctr + drag up to the EXIT and select that unwind `prepareForUnwind`. Then I'd select the UnwindSegue on the left panel and change the class to my unwind class.

The problem is, in my case I am having to create that button with code, so I don't have the option of ctr + drag. So how do I connect it to the exit and then assign the class for the unwind segue with code only? I've tried googling it, but everything keeps coming back with the method when you are using the storyboard.

I can include more code if necessary, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect your button in this way:

**First Step**

In the Storyboard connect with drag and drop your source view controller name icon with the exit icon, there you should see in the pop-up your `prepareForUnwind` function.

Then you can set for your unwind segue an identifier.

**Second step**

Add an @IBAction function for your close button and perform the segue:

```
@IBAction func closeAction() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourExitIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Just implemented it, works perfectly, thank you again!